# Can you change mail accounts by recipient in mutt?

Tags: email, mutt

I have a pretty good mutt setup for dealing with multiple mail accounts (work and personal).

I'd like to be able to have a `send-hook` that will change the account based on the recipient. I can do this with a `send-hook`, but I don't get back to the account that I was using before I sent the mail. Ideally, mutt would incorporate multiple accounts as a first-class feature, but I'm willing to hack it together if I can.

Anyone doing this already?